# Why am I getting an error message when trying to compute accuracy in VAR model?

Tags: r, var

I found this script earlier from other posts:

```
res <- residuals(Model1)
fits <- fitted(Model1)
p <- predict(Model1, n.ahead=12)
for(i in 1:6)
{
  fc <- structure(list(mean=p$fcst[[i]][,"fcst"], x=train[,i],
                       fitted=c(NA,NA,fits[,i])),class="forecast")
  Acc<-print(accuracy(fc,test[,i]))
}
my_acc <- list()
```

I am essentially trying to run an accuracy based on my train and test data, see script beneath:

```
#Declaring the selected variables as time-series
TicketSold <- ts(DF$tickets_sold, start = c(2008,2,2), frequency = 365)
TotalSales <- ts(DF$total_sales, start = c(2008,2,2), frequency = 365)
ShowTime <- ts(DF$show_time, start = c(2008,2,2), frequency = 365)
OccPerc <- ts(DF$occu_perc, start = c(2008,2,2), frequency = 365)
TicketPrice <- ts(DF$ticket_price, start = c(2008,2,2), frequency = 365)
```

With the following script, I compute my VAR model:

```
# Model Computation
v1 <- cbind(OccPerc, ShowTime, TicketPrice,TicketSold, TotalSales)
colnames(v1) <- cbind("OccPerc","ShowTime","TicketPrice","TicketSold", "TotalSales")

### Splitting our data into test and train data
dt = sort(sample(nrow(v1), nrow(v1)*.8))
train<- v1[dt,]
test<- v1[-dt,]
```

Once I try to run the accuracy, however, I get the following error message. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

```
Error in testaccuracy(object, x, test, d, D) : 
  Not enough forecasts. Check that forecasts and test data match.
In addition: Warning message:
In dx - fits :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't provided all the code that goes into your project. What libraries are you using? Which "command" are you running that returns the error?

Comment: You are right; my apologies. I just updated my post.

Comment: I can see that this is from the package forecast. The data in `object` has to be the same length as the data in `x`.  If you are using the model, you need to provide the training data. From the source code (parts of it!): `testaccuracy <- function(f, x, test, d, D); n <- length(x);  if (length(f) < n) {stop("Not enough forecasts. Check that forecasts and test data match.")}`